# Building gcc for msp430-elf target

Tags: linux, msp430, binutils, newlib, gcc4.9

I'm trying to build gcc-4.9 for msp430. I've already built the most recent version of `binutils` and have tried building `gcc-4.9` with the basic configuration:

`configure --target=msp430-elf --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-newlib=yes`

The problem though is that gcc builds itself for my machine `x86-unknown-linux` then I think it started building the `msp430` target with the new compiler but I already have gcc-4.8 installed and just want the `msp430-elf` target with the already installed `4.8`.

NOTE: `msp430` target is only avaible in `4.9` and I JUST want to build 4.9 for `msp430` not for my host machine as I already have it installed.

First of all the build failed, second, even if it did succeed I don't want to install for `x86` and I am afraid `make install` will do this.

The docs for `configure` are pretty vague and I would really appreciate some help.